# Access a dictionary value based on the list of keys

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, flask, flask-restful

I have a nested dictionary with keys and values as shown below.

```
   j = {
         "app": {
                   "id": 0,
                   "status": "valid",  
                   "Garden": {
                                "Flowers": 
                                {
                                "id": "1",                                
                                "state": "fresh"
                                },
                                 "Soil": 
                                {
                                "id": "2",                                
                                "state": "stale"
                                }
                             },

                    "BackYard": 
                           {
                                "Grass": 
                                {
                                "id": "3",                                
                                "state": "dry"
                                },
                                 "Soil": 
                                {
                                "id": "4",                                
                                "state": "stale"
                                }
                           }
                  }
         }
```

Currently, I have a python method which returns me the route based on keys to get to a 'value'. For example, if I want to access the "1" value, the python method will return me a list of string with the route of the keys to get to "1". Thus it would return me, `["app","Garden", "Flowers"]`

I am designing a service using flask and I want to be able to return a json output such as the following based on the route of the keys. Thus, I would return an output such as below.

```
      {
         "id": "1",                                
         "state": "fresh"
      }
```

The Problem:

I am unsure on how to output the result as shown above as I will need to parse the dictionary "j" in order to build it?
I tried something as the following.

```
def build_dictionary(key_chain):
    d_temp = list(d.keys())[0]
   ...unsure on how to 

#Here key_chain contains the ["app","Garden", "Flowers"] sent to from the method which parses the dictionary to store the key route to the value, in this case "1".
```

Can someone please help me to build the dictionary which I would send to the jsonify method. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you are asking:

```
def build_dictionary(key_chain, j):
    for k in key_chain:
        j = j.get(k)
    return j


kchain = ["app","Garden", "Flowers"]

>>> build_dictionary(kchain, j) 
{'id': '1', 'state': 'fresh'}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Didn't realize that it is so simple.  :)

Comment: I just had another quick question. If I had two new attributes as shown in the bold in the question above, if I used the current "build_dictionary" method, I will get the full dictionary back but I only want to be able to retrieve the `{id: 0, status: "valid" }`. I am not sure on how to do this efficiently.

Comment: @Analia If you mean that you want only keys whose values are not `dict`, could change the return statement to `return {k: v for k, v in j.items() if not isinstance(v, dict)}`, which returns `{id: 0, status: "valid" }` for `key_chain = ["app"]`.
Let me know if my interpretation is correct.